# Update user permissions in list

Tags: 2010, list, permissions

I have a list which has individual permissions set on each item. Yesterday, a cockup occurred where a number of these items had their permissions erased.

Rather than clicking each one individually, is there a way to filter the list to display only those with no permissions set? Perhaps a column with a custom content type?